# How can we use function arguments within a function declaration?

Tags: c++

The standard `N4296::3.3.4/1 [basic.scope.proto]`:

> In a function declaration, or in any function declarator except the
>   declarator of a function definition (8.4), names of parameters (if
>   supplied) have function prototype scope, which terminates at the end
>   of the nearest enclosing function declarator.

I tried the following examples:

1.

```
template<const int a>
class A{ };

const int a = 4;

A<a> b; // OK

void foo(const int a = 4, A<a>); //non-type template argument is 
                                 //not a constant expression
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46a6c880467d005c)**

2.

```
void foo(const int a = 4, int b = a); //default argument references parameter 'a'
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1531ea7698c51d4)**

How can we use this scope's feature? What is it introduced for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a contrived example:

```
void foo(overly::long_type::which_should_be_a_typedef_anyway a, decltype(a) b); // fine

decltype(a) c; // oops, a not declared
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the point of this is to say that the following code is valid:

```
extern int somefunc(int a, char *b, int c);
int somefunc(int, char *, int);

int somefunc(int number, char *bytes, int ipv4_address)
{
    …
}
```

The name `a`, `b` and `c` lose their significance at the closing parenthesis of the `extern` declaration.  Within the declarator, the names are significant to the extent that `int somefunc(int a, char *a, int a);` is invalid because the same name `a` is used where distinct identifiers are required.

The names `number`, `bytes` and `ipv4_address` do not lose their significance at the close parenthesis because that is the 'declarator of a function definition'; they become the names of variables within the function.

Note that Stroustrup explicitly declined to tie parameter names in function declarations to parameter names in function definitions.  There's a section in [Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html) that discusses this.

Comment: Nice catch, it seems to be true. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To add to user657267's example, *trailing-return-type*s often depend on this feature:

```
template<class A, class F>
auto foo(const A& a, const F& f) -> decltype(f(a));
```